# Is there any server config file to invoke MDB?

Tags: java, jboss, message-driven-bean

I am having `ejb-jar.xml` and `jboss.xml` files in my application of JMS with MDB.

I have configured the queue destination in `destination-service.xml`. But my MDB is not invoking.

Are there any server files to be configured to invoke MDB?

Comment: Telling us what files you have isn't very helpful. Show us the files - *that* would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define queue or topic only, so check if you are using proper queue name in your application.

The easiest way to check the name is to look for it in a jmx-console or in logs: JBoss prints the name of the queue. It has a prefix, so look for queue/YOUR-QUEUE-NAME, you also need to use prefixed name while talking to MDB.